# Why am I getting a different answer in Principal Component Analysis dimensional reduction?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data, machine-learning-model, dimensionality-reduction

**Problem-: Consider the two dimensional patterns (2, 1), (3, 5), (4, 3), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8).
Compute the principal component using PCA Algorithm.
Use PCA Algorithm to transform the pattern (2, 1) onto the eigen vector.**

Here is how I have solved it-:

[image: 1]

[image: 2nd picture]

[image: 3rd picture]

Here is what I am comparing with-:
https://www.gatevidyalay.com/principal-component-analysis-dimension-reduction/

He gets different eigenvector than mine-:
[image: His solution]

He also gets different transformation than mine-:
[image: His transformation to principal component]

What is going on? Am I right? How do I verify if I am right? Where am I wrong? Please guide me..